# How can two different random variables have the same probability mass functions?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a homework question that gives a function $PMF : [S → R] → [R → R]$ that maps random variables to their PMFs, and asks to show that it is not injective or surjective. With regards to the injective part, how can this function *not* be injective? It not being injective would imply that two distinct random variables could have the same PMF, so $PMF(X) = PMF(Y)$ while $X \neq Y$. Surely, however, $PMF(X) = PMF(Y)$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) = 1$ and therefore that $X$ and $Y$ are the same thing?

Comment: Two different random variables can have the same distribution.  There is a commonly used phrase, "independent identically distributed" that gets used all the time in probability theory, to describe this situation.

Comment: Determining the probability $P(X = Y)$ requires the knowledge of the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$, and in general it is not determined by the marginals - distribution of each $X$ and $Y$ - alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have discrete distributions which take values in $-1, 1$. Let $X$ be a uniform distribution on this set (i.e. takes +1 with probability 0.5 and -1 with probability 0.5). Then consider $Y=-X$. $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$. But, $P(Y=X) = 0$ ; $X$ and $Y$ are most certainly not the same random variable.

Answer (score 1):

For the injective part, you can just have different random var indicator functions, X and Y that map to the same set of outcomes.

Although, I am unclear on how would we prove show its is not surjective? I'm assuming we have to find a PMF that is not mapped by a random variable to show this to be true. But does anybody know if there are any examples of nonsurjective functions in this context that would answer this question?

Comment: Presumably, the codomain is "all functions that map $\mathbb{R}$ to itself", in which case the map would certainly not be surjective.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on that? Thank you :)

Comment: I mean that in the original context of the question, the target space of the function $PMF$ appears not to just be "the collection of probability mass functions," but rather "the collection of all real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$". Hence, this function is not surjective because there are functions that aren't pmf's of any particular random variable. (A continuous function $f$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \textrm{d} x \neq 1$ would be such a function, for instance.)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery yes, that's what my answer for the surjective part was!

Answer (score 0):

If I take a pair of fair dice, one red and one green, the two dice have the same distribution (a discrete uniform on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$), but $X - Y$ is not identically 0.