# Does same conditional distribution of two random variables imply same distribution unconditionally?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question**

Let X, Y,Z be discrete r.v.s such that X and Y have the same conditional distribution
given Z, i.e., for all a and z we have
P(X = a|Z = z) = P(Y = a|Z = z).
Show that X and Y have the same distribution (unconditionally, not just when given
Z).

**Attempt**

I tried to approach this using venn diagram which could only give me a little bit of intuition however, I am not able understand how to approach this question.

It would be really helpful if I received any story proof to this question.
Also, can we comment on the distribution of Z given the information above.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X=a) = \sum_z P(X=a|Z=z)P(Z=z) = \sum_z P(Y=a|Z=z)P(Z=z) = P(Y=a).$$

Comment: Could you provide an story proof regarding the same or a hint towards it as I am not able grasp the fact that if two random variables X and Y have same pmf for same support then, aren't they basically X=Y @TRUSKI

Comment: See here-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453777/how-can-two-different-random-variables-have-the-same-probability-mass-functions